# How to set active class on anchor links using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react on my project. But how can i handle click event on multiple elements using state. On click all elements have same class. Here is a snippet:

```
const anchors = [
     {
       id: 1,
       name: "Дансны үйлчилгээ",
       key: "account-service",
     },
     {
       id: 2,
       name: "Зээлийн үйлчилгээ",
       key: "loan-service",
     },
     {
       id: 3,
       name: "Картын үйлчилгээ",
       key: "card-service",
     },
     {
       id: 4,
       name: "Даатгалын зуучлалын үйлчилгээ",
       key: "insurance-service",
     },
     {
       id: 5,
       name: "Цахим банкны үйлчилгээ",
       key: "bank-service",
     },
     {
       id: 6,
       name: "Mэдээлэл шинэчлэх",
       key: "profile-service",
     },
   ];
```

And the loop the array:

```
<div className="positions">
    {anchors.map((anchor: any) => {
         return (
          <a
             href={"#" + anchor.key}
             key={anchor.id}
             className={active ? "selected" : ""}
             onClick={(event: any) => handleClick(event)}
          >
             <img src="/images/arrow-right.svg" />
             <span>{anchor.name}</span>
          </a>
        );
    })}
</div>
```

And my hook is

```
const [active, setActive] = useState<boolean>(false);
```

Handle event:

```
  function handleClick(e: any) {
     if (e.currentTarget) setActive(!active);
     else return;
     e.stopPropagation();
  }
```

What i want is when i click the anchor it should be `active` class. But i am stuck. I can't actually get current element and it should be active.

Comment: can you update the same with a codesandbox link

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-voice-2lffe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `active` state to record the `id` instead of a Boolean

```js
const [active, setActive] = useState<number | undefined>();
```

Then use

```
<a
  href={"#" + anchor.key}
  key={anchor.id}
  className={anchor.id === active ? "selected" : ""}
  onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, anchor.id)}
>
```

and

```js
function handleClick(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>, id: number) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  setActive(id)
}
```

[image: Edit quirky-dream-6umx1]

Comment: This is what i exactly want. Thank you so much !!! :)

Answer (score 0):

First of I would recommend using any sort of "state" for something as small as this.

You can easily get a boolean of active by doing the following in Next.js for instance (Which basically has the same router API as react):

```
const isCurrent: boolean = router.asPath == props.href;
```

Then you can add an "active" class based on this boolean or do other stuff instead like disabling the link element.

Easiest way to get this working in a DRY way is by making a wrapper for your links like this:

```
const NavBarLink = (props: { title: string; href: string }) => {
    const isCurrent: boolean = router.asPath == props.href;
    return (
      <Link
        href={props.href ? props.href : "/"}
        className={
          "block rounded py-0 pl-2 pr-2 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900" +
          (isCurrent ? " bg-gray-100 text-gray-900" : " text-white")
        }
        aria-current="page"
        aria-disabled={isCurrent}
        onClick={(e) => {
          if (isCurrent) {
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        }}
      >
        {props.title ? props.title : "--"}
      </Link>
    );
  };
```